# Built-in web part for a specific folder

Tags: web-part, document-library, folder

Is it possible, in a Sharepoint page, to add a built-in web part configured to  show only a particular folder of a Document Library? 
I have a page where I want to show 3 different web parts that point to 3 different folders of a Document Library. I didn't found that filter property in the web part property pane, neither in the filter of the views.

Comment: are you trying to add Modern Built in SPFx webpart in Modern page or its classic Document Library you are adding to a classic page

Comment: The classic one.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to filter the FolderName for Document Library in View. but surely you can create folder with different content Type and filter Against that.

Steps:

1. Create content types FolderA, FolderB and FolderC  Inherited from the "Folder" Content type.
2. Create Folder using these content Type
3. create Views by applying filters with Content Type as image below[image]
4. apply different Views on the Document Library webpart on your page

Comment: It is sad to pre-create a content-type for each folder.